# Explanation of the following commands executed one after the other

Tags: command

I have these 2 commands being executed one after the other.

```
cat a.log >> b.log
rm -r a.log
```

What is exactly happening here? Why is **cat** being used here? What about the **>> sign** ? And what is the  **-r(recursive) flag** being used?

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513)

Comment: If I was given that code in context I might suggest that the second command _intended_ to remove `a.log` rather than `b.log`, i.e. `rm -f a.log`. But not an answer because it's only conjecture

Comment: edited the ques

Comment: You cannot `cat` a directory (only the files within it), and `rm -r` only has meaning for directories. So one (or both) of those commands was written by somebody who did not know what they were doing. Also, there is no error checking. It would be nice to be sure the cat worked (e.g. b.log could be created if needed, and permissions to write, and disk not full) before discarding a.log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering your corrected code,

> ```
> cat a.log >> b.log
> rm -r a.log
> ```

1. The `cat` copies its list of files, or *stdin* if either none is supplied or a dash (`-`) is included in the list to its *stdout*. See `man cat`
2. The `>>` is a standard shell redirection operator that appends a command's output to a named file. In the example this named file is `b.log`. See `man bash` or the documentation for your preferred shell if not `bash`, and [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/100397)
3. The `rm` command (almost) unconditionally removes the file `a.log`. Because it's trying to remove a file, the `-r` flag is irrelevant and is ignored. If being run in an interactive session the command will ask the user for confirmation if the file does not have write permission. See `man rm`

If I were writing this code I would probably construct it like this

```
cat a.log >> b.log && rm -f a.log
```

Here, the removal of the `a.log` file happens only if the `cat` successfully appended its contents to the target file `b.log`.